# SQL get group value only if parameters exist in entire group values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a problem that I would like to solve in Oracle SQL. Given the table below, I would like to query it so that I pass it a list NAMEs and if they represent a single ANIMAL group, the return is that ANIMAL string.

```
+------+------+
|ANIMAL|NAME  |
+------+------+
|DOG   |LACY  |
|DOG   |CHAMP |
|DOG   |BUDDY |
|CAT   |MUFFIN|
|CAT   |CHAMP |
|FISH  |WANDA |
+------+------+
```

For example when I pass it: 
    where NAME in ('CHAMP', 'MUFFIN')
It returns:

```
+------+
|ANIMAL|
+------+
|CAT   |
+------+
```

But if I pass it: 
    where NAME in ('CHAMP', 'WANDA')
It returns:

```
 
+------+
|ANIMAL|
+------+
|FISH  |
+------+
```

Because the parameters did not contain all of the cat names, but it did within it contain all of the fish names.

Last example:
    where NAME in ('CHAMP', 'WANDA', 'LACY', 'MUFFIN')
Returns

```
 
+------+
|ANIMAL|
+------+
|CAT   |
|FISH  |
+------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
 select animal
 from t
 where name in ('CHAMP', 'WANDA', 'LACY', 'MUFFIN')
 group by animal
 having count(*) = (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.animal = t.animal)
```

It filters the table by the names you are looking for.  Then it aggregates the query.  The `having` clause compares the count of things with that name to the total count in the table.

You can also write this as:

```
 select animal
 from t
 group by animal
 having count(*) = sum(case when name in ('CHAMP', 'WANDA', 'LACY', 'MUFFIN') then 1 else 0 end)
```

This is actually better because it eliminates the subquery.